# Add a tab in Main menu phpBB3.1

Tags: phpbb3

I want to add a new tab in the main menu of phpBB forum, like in main menu on top bar next to "Forums". I am using elegance (artodia.com) theme.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making an extension for it.

Specifically your looking Here

https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb-ext-acme-demo/blob/master/styles/prosilver/template/event/overall_header_navigation_prepend.html

The overall_header_navigation_prepend event

If you download the linked repository you will be able to make a basic page also